# Build single Spring Boot WAR project for deployment

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, war

I have three projects:

```
project-A
project-B 
project-C
```

In `project-A` I have defined the data model. `Project-B` is a Spring Boot project where I define operations for consuming rest API calls with `RestTemplate`. `Project-C` is also a Spring Boot project where I am exposing some REST services.
The second project (B) requires the dependency for the first project (A). The third project (C) requires the dependencies for the first and second project (A, B). I have defined these dependencies in the respective projects (B, C) pom files. 
All three projects have `pom` packaging type.

Now I want to create a single Spring Boot WAR project for deployment on a tomcat server. My purpose is to have this single WAR that encapsulates all other projects (A, B, C). So I want to be able to make my rest services (`project-C`) accessible through this single WAR.

I tried creating a Spring Boot project with packaging type `war` and added the dependency for `project-C` (which includes the dependencies for `project-A` and `project-B`), but I am not able to deploy the generated WAR file because of a:

```
SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/mywarproject-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@af7b84d]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4842)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4974)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@517f5687]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:708)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:113)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:107)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:219)
        at java.util.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:149)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:166)
        at java.util.jar.JarFile.<init>(JarFile.java:103)
        at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:110)
```

Is there a way how can I handle this approach?

Comment: Whats the name of the WAR file?

Comment: it is sth like mywarproject-war-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Answer (score 1):

You have to package your Spring-Boot project as a war in your pom and exclude the spring-boot-starter-tomcat dependency in the spring-boot-starter-web dependency.

```
<packaging>war</packaging>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

You have to do this on your REST-Services project, which is Project-C in your case.

Comment: This solved the deployment problem of my war file in Tomcat, but now I want to access my rest services (project-C) in Tomcat. My war file does not contain any java code. It only contains the dependency of the rest services (project-C).