# how to have spring boot app and none-boot side by side

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar, war

I have two project :

1. **TRS**: spring web project that generate war file
2. **TRS-boot** : spring boot app that is jar and have config file and TRS
   app as dependency

my question is that,when I develop app I run TRS-boot and every thin is ok but when I want to give a publish to test team to run in external server , I have to create war file from TRS... 
what is the best solution to give them a app version that is war file easily?
is it good to make TRS a spring boot app and jar, if is good ....how to make war file?
please give me best solution 
thanks.

Comment: https://spring.io/guides/gs/convert-jar-to-war/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deploy Spring Boot to Tomcat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24741816/deploy-spring-boot-to-tomcat)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42394579/476716